# color ggplot line based on increasing or decreasing

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to change the color of a line segment based on whether or not it is greater than the point before it. What am I doing wrong here?

Example:

```
from [1,4] to [2,5] would be green because the y value is increasing. 
from [1,4] to [2,1] would be red because the y value is decreasing.
```

My code:

```
set.seed(42)
df<-NULL
df$x<-rnorm(10,0,10)
df$y<-rnorm(10,0,10)
df$colors<-cbind(lapply(1:length(df$x),function(i){
  ifelse(df$x[i]>df$x[i-1],"#CC6666","#9999CC")
}))
df<-data.frame(df)


ggplot()+
  geom_line(aes(x=df$x,y=df$y),size=1.5,colour=df$color)+
  scale_color_manual(values=df$color)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would something like this work for you, I re-arranged your example data a bit but we can use `geom_segment()` and `dplyr::lead()` to get the colors matched correctly and a little ggplot hack to make the labels nice again and ditch the NA:

```
set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame( x = rnorm(10,0,10),
                  y = rnorm(10,0,10) )

# base R
df <- df[order(df$x),]
df$color <- sapply(1:nrow(df), function(i) df$y[i] > df$y[i+1])
df$group <- "1"

library(tidyverse)
df <- arrange(df, x) %>% 
    mutate(color = y > lead(y),
           group = "1") # group everything togther or else we get two lines

ggplot()+
    geom_path(data = df,
              aes(x=x, y=y, color = color, group = group),size=1.5) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("#CC6666","#9999CC"), na.value = "white",
                       labels = c("increase", "decrease", ""))
```

[image]

Comment: That works great, but im kind of confused by the grouping. You arrange the variables then mutate to create a new column "1" if the value is bigger. If the value is smaller is is just automatically assigned a different group?

Comment: The group is just there because by default ggplot with try to group based on the aesthetics (if defined) so we just use "1" as a glue to make sure it keeps them all together in the same line. The arrange is just so we are doing the appropriate `i +1` comparrisons relative to order on the x-axis